Proving the equivalence of two distinct approaches to multiple regression for binary classification
I'm stuck with this peculiar problem that uses multiple linear regression in order to solve a binary classification problem (note: it's not considering the logistic version or any other GLM approach).
The problem states that the use of multiple regression as a classification method in the case of $K = 2$ classes is presented in two possible ways:

One uses two indicator variables and selects the class with the highest interpolated value (i.e. we are doing two linear regressions and the rule says to take the class corresponding to the maximum of the two predictions);
In the other case the rule is to do a single linear regression with two classes, and if the prediction is $> 0.5$ predict $1$, if the prediction is $< 0.5$ predict $0$.

Show that the two methods are equivalent.
My take on this problem is as it follows.
If we apply a single linear regression as described in point 2, we have
$$ \hat y = \begin{cases} 0 & \mbox{if } \beta_0 + x^T \beta < 0.5 \\ 1 & \mbox{if } \beta_0 + x^T \beta \geq 0.5 \end{cases} $$
If we apply the method described in point 1, let $Z$ be the response variable (i.e. a matrix with one column)
$$ Z = XB + E$$
$B$ is a $(p \times 1)$ matrix of parameters and $E$ is the error matrix. Let the 'interpolated values' for a generic point $x$ (associated with a new observation) be:
$$ \hat z = \hat B^T x, \quad \quad (x \in \mathbb{R}^K) $$
At this point in $\hat z$ I have 2 measures of propensity (to say probability would be wrong) to be 1. To classify that observation into a group I will choose the one scoring the highest propension.
And finally I don't see an algebrical way to prove that those two approaches are the same.

I don't understand the description of approach 1, but the parenthetical makes it seem to me that you just reverse the class labels 0/1?

@BenReiniger You're right, I worded it wrong, I edited the post. Basically doing two different least squares and selecting the class corresponding to the highest value predicted is the same as doing a single least squares and assigning 1 to the predicted values that are >0.5

IIUC then, the point (and one proof approach) is just that the result of the two regressions in approach (1) are related in a pretty straightforward way.

@BenReiniger How can I link the fact that I classify the observation as 0 if I score less than 0.5 in point 2 to the fact that I classify the observation as 0 if the propensity of being 0 is the highest in point 1?

This whole approach is ad hoc and not statistically principled.  As opposed to binary logistic regression as a probability estimator.

@FrankHarrell Yes, that is true and was thourougly remarked in the course I attended. The whole point was to use a tool when it's good at predicting even if it isn't backupped by theory. The equivalence of the two methods above was an exercise that I was unable to solve.

I hope the two are not equivalent as that would cast doubt on logistic regression.

I believe the approach 1 is meant as:
Let classes be A and B. Fit two linear regressions, one with targets $y_1$ defined by encoding A as 0 and B as 1, and the other with targets $y_2$ defined by encoding A as 1 and B as 0.
In that case, the target variables $y_1, y_2$ satisfy $y_2=1-y_1$, and from there OLS will produce models such that $\hat{y}_2=1-\hat{y}_1$ (this is all that's left to prove, and I hope it's believable and maybe easy for you?).
Given that, then $\hat{y}_2>\hat{y}_1$ (the criteria in approach 1 to classify as A) is equivalent to $\hat{y}_1<1/2$, as desired (this is approach 2).
